# Can Spark access DynamoDb without EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I have a set of AWS Instances where Apache Hadoop distribution along with apache spark is setup
I am trying to access DynamoDb through Spark streaming for reading and writing to the table But
During writing the Spark- DynamoDB code, I got to know emr-ddb-hadoop.jar is required to get DynamoDB Input Format and OutputFormat which is present in EMR Cluster only.
After checking few blogs it seems that it is accessible only with EMR Spark.
Is It correct?

However I use standalone JAVA SDK to access Dynamodb which worked fine

Comment: Well the jar is available `'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-emr:1.10.68'` try including it in your `spark`.

Comment: I tried to include the above dependency in my project but emr-ddb-hadoop.jar is not appeared in Maven dependency folder in project

Comment: Also which jar file contains org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat and org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat

Comment: it's this one http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb - when starting your application add the following flag `--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.10.69,aws-java-sdk-emr:1.10.68`. For instance `bin/spark-submit --packages  com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-dynamodb:1.10.69,aws-java-sdk-emr:1.10.68 ...`

Comment: this Dependency is related to Java-Dynamodb however I am looking for Spark- Dynamodb which should contain org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution of the problem.
I downloaded the emr-ddb-hadoop.jar file from EMR and using it in my environment.
Please note: To run the DynamoDB, we only need above jar only.

Comment: could you please share the code of how you created spark session with help of those jar files.? this will be extremely helpful for me. thank you

Comment: yes @Saurabh that piece of code will be a real starting point for me too